# Python most common value in list of dict

Tags: python

I have many dict in list.

```
[{'key3': '2', 'key2': '12', 'key1': '1'},
{'key3': '4', 'key2': '12', 'key1': '1'},
{'key3': '3', 'key2': '1', 'key1': '1'},
{'key3': '5', 'key2': '4', 'key1': '1'}]
```

How can I get the most recent value of the key2? This this example should print 12?

Comment: I think `my_list[0]['key2']` is the answer you are looking for *(by recent and your desired output, I am assuming the 0th entry in your list)*

Comment: What do you mean by most recent? and how come are we supposed to know the answer of the 2nd question?

Comment: Wait, recent, or common? And if you mean recent, what do you mean by that? The last value, the first value?

Comment: I mean the most common value of key2

Comment: Hi you can sort and get that value 
inp_li.sort(key=lambda x:int(x['key2']))
print inp_li[-1]['key2'] will give the max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_map = {}
for entry in my_list:
    try:
        my_map[entry['key2']] += 1
    except KeyError:
        my_map[entry['key2']] = 1
print(max(my_map, key=my_map.get))
```

You'll create a dictionary (my_map) to hold the counts. On every element of the list, store the key2 value in the map and increment the count. We need the try/except methods so that if the key does not exist, we can set it to 1. Otherwise we increment it.

At the end of the for loop my_map will look like this: `{'1': 1, '4': 1, '12': 2}`

The final line gets the max value in the list, the key2 with the highest count. We provide `key=lambda a: my_map[a]` to tell the max function to use the values of the dictionary for the max, instead of using just the keys.

Comment: It's not working good, I mean the most common value of key2

Comment: Updated the code for the new requirement, give it a shot.

Comment: thanks it wokrs perfect. I wonder, it's possible do this in shorter way?

Comment: @lukassz: If you use `collections.defaultdict(int)` instead of plain `dict` for `my_map`, you could just do `for entry in my_list: my_map[entry['key2']] += 1` with no `try`/`except` block (the `defaultdict` would provide a default value of `0` for non-existent keys).

Comment: Also you could do it in 3 lines like this: 
`my_map = {}
    [my_map.update({entry['key2']: my_map.get(entry['key2'], 0) + 1}) for entry in my_list]
    print(max(my_map.keys(), key=lambda a: my_map[a]))`